# Best approach to stream data from a JMS topic over HTTP to a HTTP client (not a browser)

Tags: http, rest, servlets, jms, websocket

I have a situation where I can't have my client connect nativity using the JMS port/protocol (I am using ActiveMQ) so I am looking for an alternative using HTTP over port 80.  What I would like to do is to create a servlet that will subscribe to a JMS topic that contains XML messages and then publish them to a persistent HTTP client which is turn will read the stream and process the messages.

Here is the stack of packages I am using

- Tomcat 7
- ActiveMQ 5.5.1
- Apache HttpClient

Most of the examples I have seen are javascript based through a web browser.  Since I am using HttpClient programmatically and not a browser, I am not sure sure on correct approach.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your application server will enable the servlet listening no problem... the usual scenario is when firewalls block the way to the client. The solution you designed is a good approach and will be tested.